# Why is 'indict' pronounced 'indite'?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

The word *indict* is not pronounced as it is spelled (big shocker in English, right?).

It looks like it should be pronounced *in-dikt*, but it is pronounced *in-dite*.

Why is it pronounced like this? Are there other words that combine *ict* to make an *ite* sound? I can think of others that are, instead, pronounced as they are spelled (eg. *edict*).

Comment: Just as a general thing: there are rather a lot of words in English whose spelling was adjusted to reflect Latin cognates *after* the word was already common in the language. *Victuals*, for instance, was *vittailes* when Chaucer wrote it, and is pronounced *vittles*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Besides *indict* and its compounds, the only other word I know of with 〈ict〉 pronounced /aɪt/ is ***deictic***, which is pronounced /ˈdaɪktɪk/.  (It has various compounds, too: *anapodeictic, endeictic, epideictic*.)  But that’s because of the 〈ei〉 not the 〈ict〉.

What’s going on with *indict* is different.  It used to be *endite* or  *indite*. **ɴᴏᴛᴇ ᴡᴇʟʟ:** We got it from the French **without** any *c* in it in the first place. So we never said what wasn’t there. (And in fact *indite* still exists but now with a somewhat different meaning.)

Regarding *indict*, though, the OED2 writes that there seems to have been some confusion along the way:

> ## **indict** /ɪnˈdaɪt/, *v.*<sup>1</sup>
>
> ### Forms
>
> - **ɑ.** 4–6 endyte, 4–7 endite, 6 endight (endict).
> - **β.** 4–9 indite, 5 indyte, (6 indyght, 6–7 indight).
> - **ɣ.** 7– indict.
>
> ### Etymology
>
> ME. *endite-n*, a. AFr. *endite-r* to indict, 
>   charge, accuse, corresponds in form to OFr. *enditer*, *-ditier*,
>   *-ditter*, answering to a late L. type **indictāre*, f. 
>   *in-* (in-<sup>**2**</sup>) + *dictāre* to say, declare, dictate. But the OFr.
>   verb is recorded only in the senses ‘make known, indicate, dictate,
>   suggest, compose, write, instruct, inform, prompt, incite’ (Godef.), so
>   that the history of the AFr. and ME. word is not clear. A corresponding   med.L. *indictāre* to indict, accuse, is cited by Du Cange only in 
>   English legal use, and seems to be merely the latinized form of the AFr. 
>   and ME. verb, in accordance with which again the ME. *endite* has been 
>   altered to *indite*, and (since 1600) written *indict*, though 
>   the spoken word remains *indite*. See also indite *v.*
>
> > The sense of *endite*, *indict*, may have 
> >   arisen from L. *indīcĕre* ‘to declare publicly’, taken as in Ital. 
> >   *indicere* ‘to denounce’ (Florio); but it comes near to a sense of L. 
> >   *indicāre* to indicate ‘to give 
> >   evidence against’; and it appears as if there had been, in late L. or
> >   Romanic, some confusion of the L. verbs *indicāre*, *indīcĕre*,
> >   *indictāre*: thus in Ital., Florio has ‘*Indicare*, to shew, to 
> >   declare, to utter; also to endite and accuse, as *Indicere*’; 
> >   ‘*Indícere*, to intimate, denounce, manifest, declare;··also to 
> >   accuse, to appeach or detect’; ‘*Indittare*, to indite; also as   *Indicere*’; ‘*Indittore*, an inditer, a denouncer; also an 
> >   intimator’.

So along with various words like *debt* and  *island*, *indict* got dubiously “Latinized” by putting in a still/now-silent letter.  The pronunciation never changed.

Comment: _Deictic_ doesn't really fit—as you yourself write, it's not pronounced /ait/ there, but /aikt/.

Comment: There are other words with *initial* "ct" pronounced /t/, e.g. ctenophore; these come from Greek, which allowed κτ/ct at the start of words. But again, not really relevant.

Comment: That's just because biologists aren't required to study Greek any more; if they still did, they could say initial stop clusters just as well as the ancients.

Answer (score 1):

Indict [came into English from Middle French](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=indite&allowed_in_frame=0), whereas other "ict" words —[predict](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/predict#Etymology), [conflict](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/conflict#Etymology)—came into English directly from Latin and retain a more Latinate pronunciation.

Comment: Hi, brasshat: your is not an answer but an assumption. Please provide reference or reliable information to questions. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You asked "are there other words pronounced this way?"

There used to be. *Interdict* used to be pronounced *interdite*, but too many people didn't know the correct pronunciation, so they started using the spelling pronunciation (or maybe they just assumed it came directly from Latin, and so used the Latin pronunciation and spelling), so now we pronounce it *interdict*.

It originally came from the French word *entredit*, so there is no etymological reason that we should pronounce the 'c'. Like *indict*, we added the 'c' to the spelling based on the Latin roots.

Many Middle English spellings of this have no "c".    From the OED:

> Forms:
> α.
> Middle English entredite, Middle English–1500s enterdite, enterdyte.
> β.
> Middle English–1600s interdyte, 1500s intredite, interdite.
> γ.
> 1500s– interdict.

The pronunciation change seems to have happened a long time ago. Shakespeare wrote (in *The Phoenix and the Turtle*)

> From this Session interdict
> Euery foule of tyrant wing,
> Saue the Eagle feath'red King,
> Keepe the obsequie so strict.

so some people were using the spelling pronunciation around 1600.

Comment: Your very informative response, @PeterShor, does include an awfully judgy segment. “Too many people were **ignorant** and didn't know the **correct** pronunciation”? Ouch.